# Reading the TinyMCE editor content in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce

Not sure if I am missing something obvious here but how do you read the editor content after a postback? The only methods I can find is to read the value using javascript and then doing an AJAX callback, but I don't want to do that.

Here is how I am rendering my TinyMCE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='path'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//My settings
</script>
<textarea id="txtTinyMce" runat="server">
</textarea>
```

Then if I attempt to read from `txtTinyMce` on postback it is empty.

Any help is appretiated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was overriding the actual value on a page load event. The above is the correct way of reading the value.